# pressure loss in a T fitting

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, hydraulics, piping

For weeks I have been searching internet , but still unable to find answer , so here it goes:
I have to calculate pressure losses in heating circuit , and am stuck at calculating losses in T fittings. Here are some crude drawings of problem [image: Flow conjunction]
[image: Flow separation]
I know:

- diameters of each pipe leading to fitting (Da,Db,Dc)
- flow rates through these pipes (Qa , Qb , Qc)

What I need to know is Pressure drops:

- ∆Pc-a=Pc-Pa=?
- ∆Pb-a=Pb-Pa=?

I know of minor loss formula , but don't understand how to use if fitting has more than 2 ports.

Comment: This may be good reading : https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1254&context=etd

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using *Handbook of Hydraulic Resistance* by I.E. Idelchik. This book is the literal bible for loss coefficient formulations. The book gives loss coefficient correlations based on test data. The image is an example of one chart provided for a tee configuration [image: One of the many charts on tee and wye data]

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways you could find a solution to that problem (actually 3 but the third is using a flow simulator :P)

Just assume that P2 and P3 are the same (or else you will find yourself in partial differential equation hell believe me been there and it isn't pretty)

1: Crane Flow of Fluids. Easy lazy, quick he gives you measured parameters for pressure loses and other things you just fit your numbers there http://www.waterlinefountains.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Crane-410.pdf

Not the best method it has a lot of error. It is the first answer that comes up in google (though they do not provide you with the tables)

2: Bird transport phenomena:

Assume it is plug flow, define a three pipe system in which 1 is the feed and 2 and 3 are the exits, you calculate each exit with an equalized pressure (or so I remember). Just to be certain; I checked the book and problem 7Q4 can give you the answer, look up the solution and define n as 2.

So far I think this is the answer you want, you calculate everything by hand but it isn't a problem with an easy solution.

I recommend you checking if someone hasn't programmed it yet because you getting a short formula is a longshot the answer to 7Q4 is a differential equation.

3: Get a copy of EPAnet (free but works poorly), HYSYS (usually colleges with Chemical engineering majors have licences) or Olga, they do pressure drops though they use method 2 and 1 combined.

TLDR: To do it by hand is possible, has been done before and that is how most simulators work, though it is so hard to do that you use equivalent lengths instead.